# Plotting a scatter plot of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
    A                B         C    
0   0.691295     0.179792   0.062371    
1   NaN          0.179915   0.102003    
2   NaN          0.186998   0.102183    
3   NaN          0.189350   0.102220    
4   NaN          0.189637   0.103003
```

How do I plot a scatter plot where

- x is an range of values from 0 to 1
- y are the column names (i.e., all values from the same column should have the same y value),
- each columns values have different colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Just some values.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.rand(5),
    'b': np.random.rand(5),
    'c': np.random.rand(5)})

# Now for the plots.

# Plot a values at 1.
plot(df.a, [1] * 5, '+');
# Plot b values at 2.
plot(df.b, [2] * 5, '+');
# Plot c values at 3.
plot(df.c, [3] * 5, '+');
# Ensure extreme points visible.
ylim(0, 4)
# Set the ticks to 'a', 'b', and 'c'.
yticks([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: Plot's just how I wanted it. Thanks.